# another way of saying experienced

Tags: synonyms

What is a different way of saying "my client has experienced something?  I am a nurse case manager who has to write functional assessments, etc.  I'm tired of using the same phrase repeatedly.  I'm referring to having hallucinations, experienced loss, trauma, grief etc.

Comment: "*Experienced*" sounds like a good word for the context you describe. So that the community can help you find an even better word, please [edit] your question to say why *experienced* doesn't work well in your context, and what qualities you're hoping to find in the word you're looking for.

Comment: Beaten on the wire by @OmidRezaAbbasi for "suffer", consider "endured".

Comment: Isn’t your primary objective here to communicate succinctly and clearly.  If ‘experienced’ is normally used and would be expected in this case, switching to something else (especially something that might not be as good or that might have other unintended implications) is probably not advisable just for a little variety.

Comment: In that context "reports" or "presents with" would often be used, emphasizing the source of your information that the client had this experience.

Comment: I second Jim and Lawrence. Experienced is the natural choice, even if it seems redundant in your...experience.

Answer (score 2):

Try synonyms: 
my client has **experienced** loss/
my client has **faced** trauma/
my client has **endured** trauma/
my client has **suffered** hallucinations/
my client has **sustained** trauma/
my client **withstood** trauma.

If the issue is ongoing, you can employ more descriptive words:

my client **suffers from** hallucinations/
my client **endures** hallucinations/
my clients has **continual** hallucinations/
my client is/was **subjected to persistent** trauma.

You can also try using the nouns themselves:

my client has had **traumatic encounters**/
my client **hallucinates**/
my client **has hallucinations**/
my client **had hallucinated**/
my client **was traumatized**.

Maybe using a different sentence structure helps.

my clients lost a family member, and feels very depressed

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **suffer / suffer from** is a better choice. As an example from *[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trauma)* about Trauma:

> She never fully recovered from the traumas she *suffered* during her
>   childhood.

Another sentence from *[Encyclopedia of Trauma: An Interdisciplinary Guide](https://books.google.com/books?id=DCd1CQAAQBAJ&pg=PT156&lpg=PT156&dq=%22suffer%20from%20Trauma%22&source=bl&ots=GtYCl45njv&sig=UxxtnCZBbnABk9eX7FZYTNs5ml8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMirrmsu_SAhXjKJoKHVbZBpkQ6AEILjAE#v=onepage&q=%22suffer%20from%20Trauma%22&f=false)* is as:

> Females who *suffer from* Trauma are more likely to present with PTSD.

Answer (score 1):

## Undergo

Works well, (past sense **undergone**)

e.g

> My patient has undergone hallucinations

Courtesy, [online dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hallucinate)

hallucinate v.intr.

> To **undergo** hallucination.

Comment: Or simply "gone through".

Comment: I disagree completely. "Undergo" places too much emphasis on the concept of going through a *process*. That doesn't apply well to experiencing hallucinations and, in the case of your example sentence, sounds really awkward.

Comment: @AleksandrH pleased to hear your disagreements! Heaven forbid, we would all believe the same... there would be no point in these boards! I would just point out that the last sentence isn't mine it's an example compiled by an editor of a dictionary (albeit the 'free dictionary' by Farlax, but it has served some 9 billion visitors so far).

Comment: The last example is actually the one I prefer. The first is the one I found a bit awkward, since "hallucinations" is more of a collective noun than a process. In contrast, I interpret the noun "hallucination" as implying the process of hallucinating, in which case "undergo" does seem appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

**"The patient presents with..."** would work for things like a rash, you can put details in between, for example; *"The patient presents with a uniform circular rash on >body part<"*

**"The patient is suffering from..."** would work with things like *"A dry cough"* or *"pain while passing urine"*.

**The patient shows evidence of..."** works with things like jaundice, concussion ect.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repetition of a particular vocabulary item, you aren't restricted to synonyms.  You can also vary the sentence structure.  Try to tell a story.  My mother worked in a state mental hospital and I once read one of her case notes.  I was surprised at how interesting they were.  She told the patient's story, in a succinct way, that was easy to follow.  I don't have an example of hers handy, so I will make something up, to try to give you an idea what I mean.

> Mr. K was raised by his mother and maternal grandmother, alternating in his early years between the two households.  He had weekly visits to his father from ages 5 to 11, at which point his mother went to court to obtain sole custody and end visitation with father.  His grandmother died after a brief illness when he was 18.  At 19, after a drug arrest, police brought him to the emergency room, where he reported hallucinations. He was admitted for treatment.  Themes that came up in treatment included grief over the loss of his grandmother and the loss of contact with his father.  He was stabilized with X meds, which were gradually reduced over a two-week period, and he transitioned to outpatient care.  Three months ago, an indecent exposure arrest brought him back to our facility etc. Mr. K recently revealed in treatment that he had two epileptic seizures at age 10, and that from age 10 to 11, his father was regularly hitting him, calling him "stupid," and subjecting him to sleep deprivation.  His new treatment plan includes weekly group therapy in the trauma group that is currently being formed and a neurology consult.

I apologize if the details and the style aren't very authentic.  I just wanted to show that you don't have to be boxed into using the same sentence structure over and over.

Answer (score -3):

Try "went through". It may not be the best replacement, especially if you are trying to emphasize a happy tone.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).